# Pandas Regular expression, more than one choice?

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a string where I was extracting the date part that looked like

```
A620170101 # output 20170101
```

In pandas I would just do something like,

```
df['var'] = df.sba.str.extract(r'A6(.{8})', expand=False)
```

However, now I need to update to also extract the date from a string that looks like

```
JT20170101 # output 20170101
```

I tried added a `|` but that didn't work.

Here is a quick test data,

```
d = {'var1': 'A620170101', 'var2': 'JT20170102', 'var3': '', 'var4': 'TG20170102'}
pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()), columns=['var', 'sba'])
```

I just want the date part with the A6 and JT prefix.

Comment: Use `r'(?:JT|A6)(\d{8})'` or `r'^(?:JT|A6)(\d{8})$'`  to match the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

Use solution from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49955519/pandas-regular-expression-more-than-one-choice/49955559#comment86927501_49955519):

```
df['var3'] = df.sba.str.extract(r'(?:JT|A6)(.{8})', expand=False)
print (df)
    var         sba      var3
0  var1  A620170101  20170101
1  var2  JT20170102  20170102
2  var3                   NaN
3  var4  TG20170102       NaN
```

Another solution is check first 2 values and if in list extract from `2` to `10` value:

```
df['var3'] = np.where(df.sba.str[:2].isin(['A6','JT']), df.sba.str[2:10], np.nan)
print (df)
    var         sba      var3
0  var1  A620170101  20170101
1  var2  JT20170102  20170102
2  var3                   NaN
3  var4  TG20170102       NaN
```

Comment: Oh dang I need to update my question, I need either `A6` or `JT` but there could be others.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the "|" operator, you could try something like:

```
(?:JT|A6)(.{8})
```

The previous answer is good too.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is always the same length, like shown above, you could skip using a regex and just grab the first two characters for the code and a grab of the last 8 characters for the date.

If you want a regex that captures any prefix code (of any length) and the date suffix you could use this:

```
(.*)(\d{8})
```

I'm not familiar with panda but I'm assuming that it works with this.

Comment: Unfortunately not, check last OP sentence `I just want the date part with the A6 and JT prefix.`

Comment: @jezrael. Then he could do a separate grab of the first two characters as well. If the strings are always the same length and look like the above, a regex seems like overkill in this case.

Comment: Yop, It depends of data,